# Unable to process binding - is undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to expand my knowledge of KnockoutJS (I have a high level understanding). I am building a front end which talks to my business logic / data access via Web API. I am able to read from the API, but I am trying to build the insert form, and getting the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return startTime }"
Message: startTime is not defined

Here is the LessonViewModel.js

```
var lessonRegisterViewModel;

function Lesson(id, name, teacher, room, subject, startTime, endTime) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Teacher = ko.observable(teacher);
    self.Room = ko.observable(room);
    self.Subject = ko.observable(subject);
    self.StartTime = ko.observable(startTime);
    self.EndTime = ko.observable(endTime);
    self.addLesson = function() {
        var dataObject = ko.toJSON(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Lessons',
            type: 'post',
            data: dataObject,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                lessonRegisterViewModel.lessonListViewModel.lessons.push(new Lesson(data.Id, data.Name, data.Teacher, data.Room, data.Subject, data.StartTime, data.EndTime));
                self.Id(null);
                self.Name('');
                self.Teacher('');
                self.Room('');
                self.Subject('');
                self.StartTime('');
                self.EndTime('');
            }
        });
    }
}

function LessonList() {
    var self = this;
    self.lessons = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.getLessons = function() {
        self.lessons.removeAll();
        $.getJSON('/api/Lessons', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                self.lessons.push(new Lesson(value.id, value.name, value.teacher, value.room, value.subject, value.startTime, value.endTime));
                console.log(self);
            });
        });
    };
    self.removeLesson = function(lesson) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Lessons/' + lesson.Id(),
            type: 'delete',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function() {
                self.lessons.remove(lesson);
            }
        });
    }
}
lessonRegisterViewModel = {
    addLessonViewModel: new Lesson(),
    lessonListViewModel: new LessonList()
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind view model to referring view
    ko.applyBindings(lessonRegisterViewModel);
    // load lesson data
    lessonRegisterViewModel.lessonListViewModel.getLessons();
});
```

Here is my view:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inpLessonName">Lesson Name</label>
        <input id="inpLessonName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: name" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inpStartTime">Start Time</label>
        <input id="inpStartTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" data-bind="value: StartTime" />
    </div>
</form>

<input type="button" id="btnAddLesson" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Lessons" data-bind="click: " />
```

If you could point out my mistake, and anything else you foresee as a problem I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Your cases don't match. startTime vs StartTime.

Comment: That's just a paste fail. The error does persist with matching cases.

Comment: **1.** `StartTime` is defined on each `Lesson`, so unless you're inside `foreach: lessons` it won't bind (See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). **2.** The object you're passing to the `applyBindings()` method is your view-model. Currently, the path to your `lessons` array is actually `lessonListViewModel.lessons` and not simply `lessons`. Perhaps you can add `data-bind="with: lessonListViewModel` on some root container or the body (or call `applyBindings(lessonRegisterViewModel.lessonListViewModel)` without the wrapping object).